# OleDbDataAdapter Access not finding table

Tags: sql, ado.net

I've got a  problem finding the data for one particular table. I've output the SQL statement and tested it in a query in Access and that query finds the relevant data, but in the code the dataset returns zero rows.

```
Private m_comm As OleDbCommand
Private m_SQL As String
Private m_ds As New DataSet
Private m_dt As New DataTable
Private m_da As OleDbDataAdapter
Private m_bd As OleDbCommandBuilder

' bit of code to connect to database
m_conn = ...

m_comm = New OleDbCommand
m_comm.Connection = m_conn
m_SQL = "SELECT * FROM [TableName];"
m_ds = New DataSet
m_dt = New DataTable
m_da = New OleDbDataAdapter(m_SQL, m_conn)
Dim n As Integer = m_da.Fill(m_ds)
```

At this point n = 0

This is the only table this happens with. The Table contains 1 row with two fields.

I've been trying to figure out what might be happening, but I need another set of eyes in case I'm missing the obvious. I have other tables with the same configuration and the SQL for them work so it's not the 1 row that is the problem....

Comment: If you removing the `;` will it work?

Comment: I've tried with and without the ;
I've tried with [] with `` and without anything on the table name.
All work in Access Query SQL but not in the code.

Comment: and your connection string, try to call the `Open()` method from the connection object to see it is valid.

Comment: The connection is permanently open and 32 SELECT statements have been successfully performed before this fail.

Comment: your code looks ok ... there must be a problem in the part you left out ... what seems to be a bit strange is that you create a DataTable m_dt and don't use it anywhere ...

Comment: Yes, that was a start to expand on a suggestion make elsewhere. I personally don't think it's needed...